# How do I give a .gif height and width when inserted with onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that has jpegs that switch to gifs when you hover over them. I do this using this code

```
<img src="images/e911_icon_vi_site_2014_white.jpg" onmouseover="this.src = 'images/e911_icon_vi_site_2014_white.gif'" onmouseout="    this.src = 'images/e911_icon_vi_site_2014_white.jpg'" class="servicesimages">
```

I gave it a class of service images so I can apply this style

```
.servicesImages{
    height:300px;
    width:412px;

}
```

The class worked when it was just a normal image. However, now that its a rollOver image, the class doesnt apply and the image defaults to its normal size, for both the gif and the jpeg.

A live example can be seen [HERE](http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/services.html)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Im not sure i quite understand but the big image had a typo in the class `servicesimages` change it to `servicesImages` and it should work.

Comment: Wow. cant believe i didnt notice that. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you dont need JavaScript to do this. You can use only pure CSS.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aloisdg/Zh7pD/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgif"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgif {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius:50%;

    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/400/400");
}

.imgif:hover {
     background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/YzGK6hf.jpg");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height and width in your onmouseover handler like this:

```
onmouseover="this.src = 'images/e911_icon_vi_site_2014_white.gif'; this.style.height = '50px';"
```

However, you might want to change your approach to using CSS. Then you can use a :hover class instead of messing with mouse handlers. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tZLGZ/).

```
#Service1 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Avenger__Westphalian_horse.jpg');
    background-size: 300px 300px;
}

#Service1:hover {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: url('http://www.canadianpetconnection.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/horse-OSPCA.jpg');
    background-size: 300px 300px;
}
```

Comment: In your sample, you can remove `height`, `width`, and `background-size` from the `hover` selector. It keep the property of the element. By the way, `background` is an alias of a lot of `background` propery. In this case, just use `background-image`.